# APNS2 error 400: DeviceTokenNotForTopic - Getting this error when sending Push Notification via PubNub

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

As the title says, I am getting

```
APNS2 error 400: DeviceTokenNotForTopic
```

When trying to send notification to apple device from PubNub console and listening to the events on `-pndebug` channel.

Neither Apple not PubNub provides a document to address this issue.

I have already verified the certificates used for app distribution and the ones uploaded on PubNub console.

Comment: It may be that you are using Push Certificates but you are publishing a message with bundle_ids (topics) in them or your PubNub key set is misconfigured. Please send your inquiry to [PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/support) and include the link to this SO post so we can post back with the answer. We need your PubNub sub-key to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi @craig. You have already helped me solve the issue yesterday via support. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so we have an answer for this, the issue was PubNub account config related and likely not something that will affect anyone else using PubNub for push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You must check your APNS_TOPIC. I have same mistake when tried send push with wrong APNS_TOPIC.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate user_id and topic should be same. Please check that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31278726)